# Bash : Verify empty folder before ls -A

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm starting to study some sh implementations and im running into some troubles when trying to do some actions with files inside some folders.

Here is the scenario:

I have a list of TXT files inside two different subfolders :

```
├── Folder A
    ├── randomFile1.txt
    ├── randomFile2.txt
    ├── Folder B
        ├── File1.txt
    ├── Folder C
        ├── File2.txt
```

And depending of the folder that the file resides in, i should take an specify action.

obs1 : The files from folderA should not be processed.

basicaly i tried two different aprroachs:

first one :

```
files_b="$incoming/$origin"/FolderB/*.txt
files_c="$incoming/$origin"/FolderC/*.txt

if [ "$(ls -A $files_b)" ]; then
   for file in $files_b
   do
     #take action
   done
else
    echo -e "\033[1;33mWarning: No files\033[0m"
fi


if [ "$(ls -A $files_c)" ]; then
   for file in $files_c
   do
     #take action
   done
else
    echo -e "\033[1;33mWarning: No files\033[0m"
fi
```

the problem for this one is that when i run the command ls -A if one of the folders (B or C) is empty, it throws an error because of the " *.txt " in the end of the path.

The second :

```
path="$incoming/$origin"/*.txt

    find $path -type f -name "*.txt" | while read txt; do
      for file in $txt
        do
            name=$(basename "$file")
            dir=$(basename $(dirname $file))   

            if [ "$dir" == FolderB]; then
                # Do something to files"
            elif [ "$dir" == FolderC]; then
                # Do something to files"
            fi  
         done   
    done
```

For that approach the problem is that i'm picking the files from folder A and i dont want that (because it will decrease performance due to "if" statements), and i dont know how to verify if the folder is empty using the find command.

Can annyone help me?

Thank you all.

Comment: Redirect stderr of `ls -A` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Very well formatted and explained question. Worth the UV. Keep up the good work. (it has been rarely seen lately...)

Comment: In the second one, it should be `path="$incoming/$origin"/`. The `*.txt` on the end expands into matching files, which then make the subsequent `find` kind of pointless. (You also don't want that for loop inside the while loop)

Comment: Some notes. (1) `==` shouldn't be used in `[ ]` -- the only POSIX-specified string comparison operator is `=`; see the relevant standard document at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (2) in general, [`ls` shouldn't be used in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). To check if a directory is empty, see [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Comment: You shouldn't think of `ls` as a tool for getting lists of files -- it's a tool for *displaying* lists of files to the user. In this case, the shell is expanding the wildcard expression into a list of files, and `ls` is just looking at the result(s) and either saying "yep, that's a file all right" and printing it, or "nope, no file by that name" and printing an error. And the `-A` option isn't doing anything at all (again, because `ls` isn't what's generating the list of files).

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`? `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first solution you can simply hide the error messages.

```
if [ "$(ls -A $files_b 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
```

In the second solution, start `find` at the subdirectories instead of the parent directory:

```
path="$incoming/$origin/FolderA $incoming/$origin/FolderB"
```

Answer (score 4):

I would write the code like this:

1. No unquoted parameter expansions
2. Don't use `ls` to check if the directory is empty
3. Use `printf` instead of `echo`.

---

```
# You cannot safely expand a parameter so that it does file globbing
# but does *not* to word-splitting. Put the glob directly in the loop
# or use an array.
shopt -s nullglob
found=
for file in "$incoming/$origin"/FolderB/*.txt; do
do
  found=1
  #take action
done
if [ "$found" ]; then
    printf "\033[1;33mWarning: No files\033[0m\n"
fi
```

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I forget to use `nullglob`....

Comment: @Socowi, or `[ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ] || break` to handle the case where the glob successfully expands to a broken symlink

Comment: I always recommend turning off `nullglob` afterward (i.e. `shopt -u nullglob`), to avoid unexpected behavior from things like `grep somepattern *.txt` (which will read from stdin if the `*.txt` glob doesn't match anything and hence vanishes).

Comment: as Gordon says: save `nullglob` state before enabling `shopt -q nullglob; nullglob=$?`; and to restore it: `((nullglob))&&shopt -u nullglob`

Answer (score 1):

I think using **find** should be better

```
files_b="${incoming}/${origin}/FolderB"
files_c="${incoming}/${origin}/FolderC"

find files_b -name "*.txt" -exec action1 {} \;
find files_b -name "*.txt" -exec action2 {} \;
```

or even just find

```
find "${incoming}/${origin}/FolderB" -name "*.txt" -exec action1 {} \;
find "${incoming}/${origin}/FolderC" -name "*.txt" -exec action2 {} \;
```

of course you should think about your action, but you can make function or separate script which accept file name(s)